# Слова в цифры (один>1)

Tags: javascript

Нужно перевести слова в цифры, например: один>1, десять>10 и т.д.

Comment: @Lolpetr, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Не понимаю, как сделать это, хотел через replace, но не думаю, что это хорошо.

Comment: В простом случае `replace()` — то, что нужно. В более сложном, проще воспользоваться API какого-то из [сервисов NLP](http://blog.mashape.com/post/48946187179/15-natural-language-processing-apis) в хорошем смысле слова (Natural Language Processing).

Answer (score 1):

Похожий вопрос уже когда-то поднимался тут. "Игра не стоит свеч". Если с цифрами всё не так печально и можно использовать массив для замещения, например,

```
var numArr = ['ноль','один','два','три','четыре'];
console.log(numArr.indexOf('три')); // выведет 3
```

То с числами всё гораздо сложнее. Задумайтесь над тем, как вы будете выискивать в общем контексте многозначное число? Но, даже если вы и смогли получить число прописью, то на этом сложности не заканчиваются. Нужно создать несколько массивов:

1. Где будут все варианты написания чисел прописью от 0 до 999
2. Со всеми вариантами написания разрядов прописью (окончания): ['тысяч','а','и',''], ['миллион','','а','ов'] и т.д.

А далее продумать алгоритмы для разных вариантов: с учетом и без учета возможных окончаний.

Comment: особенно учитывая все особенности склонения числительных по падежам в русском языке.  Например: четыреста пятьдесят шесть, четырехсот пятидесяти шести, четыремстам пятидесяти шести, четыреста пятьдесят шесть, четырьмястами пятьюдесятью шестью, о четырехстах пятидесяти шести - замучаетесь все это разбирать

Comment: Обнадёживает, что множество правил всё же конечно : )

Comment: не забудьте про столь же многочисленные исключения из множества правил))